# Accept() take too long time to return in golang

Tags: networking, go

I work on a tcp server in golang ,recently I found a problem, when the client connected to the server, use `netstat -nat|grep -i "55555"` to check , it tells me the connection has established and   Recv-Q has message ,  but `Accept()` need take about several seconds to return . I'm confused about it, could anyone tell me why or give any advice how to find the problem?

Here is my main code

```
tcpAddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp4", server.Host)
if err != nil {
    log.Error(err.Error())
    os.Exit(-1)
}
listener, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp", tcpAddr)
if err != nil {
    log.Error(err.Error())                                                                                                                                               
    os.Exit(-1)
}
for {
    conn, err := listener.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        continue
    }
    log.Debug("Accept a new connection")
    go handleClient(conn)//deal the connection 
}
```

P.S.
In `handleClient`, it's too long, I can't paste it here, only one more thing, I set `tcp keep alive` to the connection , use this package `github.com/felixge/tcpkeepalive`

```
    kaConn, err := tcpkeepalive.EnableKeepAlive(connection)
    if err != nil  {
        log.Debug("EnableKeepAlive err ", err)
    }else{
        kaConn.SetKeepAliveIdle(30*time.Second)
        kaConn.SetKeepAliveCount(4) 
        kaConn.SetKeepAliveInterval(5*time.Second)
    }
```

Update :

When I stop `tcp keep alive`, it works and `Accept` return instantly .

But even if not stop tcp keep alive, `Accept` return instantly when I use a script to test.Is it to do with the client?

Comment: What does handleClient look like? because I can't reproduce that at all.

Comment: Yes ,recently I get this problem , it was ok before. `handleClient` is long, just to deal with details.Is it to do with acccpt when doing something in `handleClient`?

Comment: like I said I tried it locally and the response time is < 7ms, can you try to remove the keepalive lines and see if that helps?

Comment: Yes, it works, strange

Comment: You need to `conn.Close()` after handling the connection. If you don't do that you run out of file descriptors and that may explain the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: This might be because go routines are not pre-empted; they run until they block, and then another go routine gets to run. Does the situation improve if you set `GOMAXPROCS` to, say, 4?

Comment: @ams: that's incorrect. In general scheduling is checked on checked on function boundaries, you don't need to block to be rescheduled. A real busy-loop however can tie up the scheduler for an indeterminate amount of time, but that's usually a bug in the code and increasing GOMAXPROCS only masks it.

Comment: @JimB, OK, so single-function go routines might be a problem, but those are unlikely. Still, if there are a lot of go routines active it might still be just general busyness slowing the accept.

Comment: @ams: I also forgot to mention channel send and receive operations. Basically, the only thing that really blocks is a busy-loop that's doing nothing externally visible. That's easily detectable by checking CPU usage. Since removing the Keepalive calls fixes it, I'm suspecting something with the network stack.